# Difficulties creating a jar file

Tags: java, jar, editor

I wrote a code using Java Editor and now I am trying to create a jar File from it. Creating one from my early codes (just Hello World and stuff) worked well. But with this code it seems not to work. Java Editor says that it compressed  until 48% and then it stops. Opening the jar does not work. I looked up a lot of "tutorials" on creating a jar file but all of them just showed how to press the button on the top, which I did. I also tried Jarfix (didn't work). Can anyone here help me?

Comment: Can you post the code you are trying to write?

Comment: Is it a "Runnable jar" ? Is it GUI or just command line ? You wont see anything by clicking on it if your code does not open a frame.

Comment: Sorry if I write this in the wrong place, as this is my first time on this site. It's an code that's executed in a console. Not in a JFrame (I don't know others)

Answer (score 1):

- Step 1: Create a directory named `proj` (or any other name) to
  isolate your work from existing files.
- Step 2: Within that directory of step 1, create another directory
  named `com` and within `com` create one more directory named `quest`.
- Step 3: Now put the following Hello.java in the directory named
  quest.

  ```
  package com.quest;
  public class Hello{

  public static void main(String[] args){
      if(args.length==0){
          System.out.println("Hello World");
      }else{
          System.out.println("Hello "+args[0]);

      }
   }
  }
  ```
- Step 4: Create a text file named `MANIFEST.MF` in `proj` directory with following content.
  Please remember to press enter after typing the last line (here only one line) of the file.

  `Main-Class: com.quest.Hello`
- Step 5: Open command prompt at the directory named `proj`. Compile the
  `Hello.java` with following command. Assuming that `javac` is in
  your PATH.
  `C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\proj>javac com\quest\Hello.java`
- Step 6: Create executable hello.jar file with following command:

  `C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\proj>jar cmf MANIFEST.MF hello.jar com`
- Step 7: Run it:

  `C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\proj>java -jar hello.jar Infonyx`

  [image]

  Details are available here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

  Please let me know it works or not.