# How to get two dimensional array from runnable jar on PHP

Tags: java, php, jar

I ran a runnable jar file from command line.

the runnable jar file contains only  code like following.

```
public static List<List<String>> main(String[] args) {
  String key = args[0];
  String value = args[1];
  return test(key,value);   
}
private static List<List<String>> test(String key,String Value) {
    List<List<String>> keylist = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
      List<String> valuelist = new ArrayList<String>();
      valuelist.add(i+key);
      valuelist.add(i+Value);
      keylist.add(valuelist);
    }
    System.out.println(keylist.get(1).get(1));
     return keylist;
}
```

this is the code from php

```
<?php
   echo shell_exec("java -jar /Users/Test/Desktop/test.jar", $output);
?>
```

but i got nothing from $output ,
How can I get output after running the jar file on PHP and print to table?

Thanks in advance for your answer and sorry for my poor English. If you don't understand my question please make a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please put the executable jar `test.jar` in the directory where your `PHP` file is located. Now following is the content of the PHP file:

```
<?php
   $output = shell_exec('java -jar test.jar good bad');  
   echo "output is $output"
?>
```

Please tell me do you see any output or not?

I have slightly modified your class as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String key = args[0];
    String value = args[1];
    List<List<String>> results = test(key, value);
    System.out.println(results);
}

private static List<List<String>> test(String key, String Value) {
    List<List<String>> keylist = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        List<String> valuelist = new ArrayList<String>();
        valuelist.add(i + key);
        valuelist.add(i + Value);
        keylist.add(valuelist);
    }
    System.out.println(keylist.get(1).get(1));
    return keylist;
}

}
```

And on running it by passing two command line arguments `good` and `bad`, I get following output:

```
1bad
[[0good, 0bad], [1good, 1bad], [2good, 2bad], [3good, 3bad], [4good, 4bad], [5good, 5bad], [6good, 6bad], [7good, 7bad], [8good, 8bad], [9good, 9bad]]
```

Comment: pass two argument is still get nothing

Comment: @matt.crawfoord Can you execute this jar on command prompt? What happens when you open the command prompt and type: `java -jar test.jar good bad`?

Comment: @matt.crawfoord Then it is not an executable jar. You need to add `Main-Class` attribute to the `MANIFEST.MF` file present inside the jar file. Can you tell me what is name of the Class having the `main` method?

Comment: for the example the class name is  test

Comment: @matt.crawfoord Could you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37528983/difficulties-creating-a-jar-file/37530424#37530424 on how to create an executable jar?

Comment: now i have crate jar as you said ,but still get nothing in php

Comment: When you run the Jar on command prompt,  Do you see any output?

Comment: @matt.crawfoord I have edited my answer. Please have a look at it. I have run the code on my system. It has worked for me. Thanks for being patient.