# how to create a jar file of a code written in a package?

Tags: java

So i created a notepad swing app in java. I have all my images and .class files in a folder named notepad on desktop in windows. Also my notepad main class is in a package named notepad. Its something like this .

```
package notepad; 
......

class notePad

........
```

All the contents are in a folder named notepad on desktop. Please guide me on how to create an exexutable jar file for my source code . I already tried using jar cmf command but it gives file not found exception .

Comment: So, how did you try creating it? From which directory, using which command? Have you executed `jar -h` and read the help message?

Comment: Using an IDE would simplify the process, but the documentation tells you how to [Create a JAR file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)

Comment: Just export your project using Eclipse IDE as runnable jar to get it going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's understand what a JAR actually is. JAR (Java Archive) is simply a ZIP file that contains resources (class files, metadata files, resource files (images, etc.)).

So, assuming you have a structure that looks like this:

```
 notepad
      |- notePad.class
      |- img1.jpg
```

Create a directory inside notepad called `META-INF`. This is the **meta** **inf**ormation about this jar. Inside `META-INF` create a file called `MANIFEST.MF`. This file will contain the information for java to know how to run the jar.

So now, your directory looks like this:

```
 notepad
      |- notePad.class
      |- img1.jpg
      |- META-INF
           |- MANIFEST.MF
```

Now, let's write the MANIFEST.MF.

Inside the MANIFEST.MF, write the following contents:

```
 Main-Class: notePad
```

Now, zip up the contents of the notepad directory into a zip file. Replace .zip with .jar, then execute using `java -jar notepad.jar`.

Make sure the top level resources are preserved! Don't zip up notepad into itself.

Comment: The main class is `notepad.nodePad`, not `notePad`. The META-INF folder should be at the root. And the JDK has a jar command, that allows including a manifest file directly, without having to put it into the classes directory.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please have a look at the answer given at: [Difficulties creating a jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37528983/difficulties-creating-a-jar-file)

Hope, you will have no problem in creating an executable Jar after reading the above answer.

Comment: Tried all the steps , still no success

Comment: What problems are you facing?

Comment: I am trying the command , but error comes up in the cmd, whic says file not found exception <access is denied>

Comment: Could you please be tell us exactly what command you are typing and what error you are getting? If possible please provide screenshots.